# Does the alternating series test apply to this?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

[image]

I am sure that the ratio test is inconclusive.
The alternating series test is doubtful because the series is increasing at and around 1. 
And for the comparative test, do I do it for the absolute value or the entire thing?
What'd the conclusion and answer to 4 be?

Answer (score 1):

Convergence of a series does not depend on the first few terms. You can simply omit the first term of this series and apply alternating series test.

Answer (score 0):

You can toss out finitely many terms of the series when performing an asymptotic test.

At what point does $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4+3}}$ start to decrease? What does this say about the truncated series? How does this determine the fate of the original series?

Comment: Thank you. About the comparison test, do I do it for the absolute value of the expression or do I include the (-1)^k?

Comment: You use the alternating series test and ignore the first few terms since their sum is finite. I'm not sure how the comparison test would help.